# Unpredictable Cloudfront 502 errors

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront, aws-cdk

I have an AWS setup which involves

- A custom domain name attached too
- A cloudfront distribution with
- An API gateway as the origin in front of
- Some lambda functions that render some nextJS routes generated by `https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-aws-lambda-webpack-plugin`

The provisioning code uses CDK. I've tried to remove everything that is not relevant, so the minimal example (which is unfortunately not that minimal, sorry) is at the bottom of the question.

The problem is that it seems to work, *most* of the time. But I seem to be getting unpredictable "CloudFront wasn't able to connect to the origin" errors and I'm really not sure why. There is [some documentation on this from aws](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/resolve-cloudfront-connection-error/) but its not really clear to me how to go about verifying which of these it is. If anyone has any suggestions it would be incredibly helpful

```js
import { Stack, StackProps } from "aws-cdk-lib";
import * as cdk from "aws-cdk-lib";
import { Cors, LambdaIntegration, RestApi } from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-apigateway";
import { Code, LayerVersion, Runtime, Function } from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda";
import { DnsValidatedCertificate } from "aws-cdk-lib/lib/aws-certificatemanager";
import { Distribution, ViewerProtocolPolicy } from "aws-cdk-lib/lib/aws-cloudfront";
import { ARecord, PublicHostedZone, RecordTarget } from "aws-cdk-lib/lib/aws-route53";
import { CloudFrontTarget } from "aws-cdk-lib/lib/aws-route53-targets";
import { Construct } from "constructs";
import { HttpOrigin } from "aws-cdk-lib/lib/aws-cloudfront-origins";

interface Props {
  path1: string;
  path2: string;
  layerPath: string;
}

export class AppStack extends Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: StackProps & Props) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const awsNextLayer = new LayerVersion(this, "aws-next-layer", {
      code: Code.fromAsset(props.layerPath),
    });

    const functionOne = new Function(this, `function-one`, {
      functionName: 'function-one',
      runtime: Runtime.NODEJS_14_X,
      handler: "page/handler.render",
      code: Code.fromAsset(props.path1),
      layers: [awsNextLayer],
    });

    const functionTwo = new Function(this, `function-one`, {
      functionName: 'function-one',
      runtime: Runtime.NODEJS_14_X,
      handler: "page/handler.render",
      code: Code.fromAsset(props.path1),
      layers: [awsNextLayer],
    });

    const api = new RestApi(this, "pages-api", {
      defaultCorsPreflightOptions: {
        allowOrigins: Cors.ALL_ORIGINS,
      },
      restApiName: `api`,
    });

    api.root.addResource('function-one').addMethod("GET", new LambdaIntegration(functionOne));
    api.root.addResource('function-two').addMethod("GET", new LambdaIntegration(functionTwo));

    const domainName = `dev.app.my-domain-name.com`

    const hostedZone = new PublicHostedZone(this, "HostedZone", {
      zoneName: domainName,
    });

    const certificate = new DnsValidatedCertificate(this, "cert", {
      domainName,
      hostedZone,
      region: "us-east-1",
    });

    const apiGatewayDomainName = `${api.restApiId}.execute-api.${cdk.Aws.REGION}.amazonaws.com`;

    const origin = new HttpOrigin(apiGatewayDomainName, { originPath: "/prod" });

    const distribution = new Distribution(this, "cdn", {
      domainNames: [domainName],
      defaultBehavior: {
        origin,
        viewerProtocolPolicy: ViewerProtocolPolicy.REDIRECT_TO_HTTPS,
      },
      certificate,
    });

    new ARecord(this, "a-record", {
      zone: hostedZone,
      recordName: domainName,
      target: RecordTarget.fromAlias(new CloudFrontTarget(distribution)),
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: Did you check your lambda function for any errors which may correlate with CloudFront issues?

Comment: Yup. Nothing :(

Comment: Do you have API Gateway logging turned on? You might find some clue there

Comment: What happens if you remove all logic from the Lambda and return ack/200 all requests? I'm curious if you're eating the problem in the Lambda origin.

Answer (score -1):

When I've had this issue in the past, it's been due to the lambda timing out.  The default timeout value is 3 seconds.  Try increasing to 30 on your functions:

```
timeout: Duration.seconds(30)
```

It's really hard to tell that is the issue because the lambda logs won't have an error it'll just say something like 3000 billed for lambda.

Comment: It's not that hard to tell though. There's a literal error in the CloudWatch logs if that happens: `Task timed out after 3.00 seconds` for example.